# How many times does clock B show the right time?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

There are two analog clocks. Clock A works as normal, but clock B goes backward and seven times as fast. How many times in 24 hours will clock B show the right time (same as A). Meaning how many times do the short hands align?

I found similar questions at [How to visualize this modular arithmetic problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3321623/how-to-visualize-this-modular-arithmetic-problem) and [One clock gains, another clock loses time. When will both clocks next show the same time?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1187127/one-clock-gains-another-clock-loses-time-when-will-both-clocks-next-show-the-s).

But I'm having a hard time using the same logic since one clock works backward. The right answer is 16 if you don't count the last alignment since it's not the same day anymore.

I solved the problem by just drawing clocks and tables. It was not too time-consuming for this question, but I would like to know a more efficient way of solving the problem using modular arithmetic. For example, transferring the problem into a congruence.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the number the short hand of clock $A$ represents, then
$$x \equiv12-7x \text{ (mod $12$)} $$
or
$$ 8x \equiv 0 \text{ (mod $12$)}$$
since we only consider $24$ hours, $x \in [0, 24)$, and there are
$$8x = 0, 12, 24, ..., 12*15$$
or
$$x = 0, \frac{12}{8}, \frac{24}{8}, ..., \frac{12*15}{8}$$
a total of $16$ solutions.